# How to get html select option value with ng-model angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to show value on select option with `ng-model` but value doesn't show. This is my update page, so i must need ng-model from which i send my country_id also i need to show country name here is my code

```
<select  data-ng-model="ticket[0].country_id" ng-option="x in ticket['get_country']"id="country">

                          <option   value="{{ x.name }}">{{ x.name }}
</option>
</select>
```

this is the code from which i get the name of country from angularjs code

```
.then(
            function successCallback(response) {    
                console.log(response.data['get_country'][0]['name']);
                $scope.country = response.data['get_country'][0] ['name'] 
                $scope.ticket = response.data;    
            },
            function errorCallback(response) {
                alert("Error. Try Again!");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ng-options** like this

```
<select  data-ng-model="ticket[0].country_id" ng-option="x.name as x.name for x in ticket['get_country']"id="country"></select>
```

if you print the model, you can see the name of the item that what you selected.

Comment: this is my code
  `<select  data-ng-model="ticket[0].country_id" ng-option="x.name as x.name for x in ticket['get_country']"id="country"></select>

                                           
                          <option   value="{{ x.name }}">{{ x.name }}
</option>
    <?php
foreach ($country as $row) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row->id . '">' . $row->name . '</option>';
}
?>
   </select>`
i am getting all countries like this i need to show only country that i am getting from angular js then if user want to change the country user can select country from list

Comment: You mean by default option selection in select box? By the way i don't think you  need option tag in the above code, as you used ng-options.